# How do I adds a substring to every column in kdb

Tags: kdb

My current columns in kdb is `(Time;Buy;Sell)`. What should I do to change my column names to `(Time_hist;Buy_hist;Sell_hist)`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following expression will append `"_hist"` to all column names

```
(`$(string cols t),\:"_hist") xcol t
```

where `t` is table.

1. `string cols t` - retrieves all column names and converts them to strings
2. `(string cols t),\:"_hist"` appends `"_hist"` to each column name on the left
3. `colnames xcol t` renames table column names. See [xcol](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cols/) for more details

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xcol` to rename columns in kdb:

```
q)tab:([] Time:(.z.t-10;.z.t-5;.z.t);Buy:23 35 42;Sell:22 33 40)
q)tab
Time         Buy Sell
---------------------
15:51:50.746 23  22  
15:51:50.751 35  33  
15:51:50.756 42  40  
q)`Time_hist`Buy_hist`Sell_hist xcol tab
Time_hist    Buy_hist Sell_hist
-------------------------------
15:51:50.746 23       22       
15:51:50.751 35       33       
15:51:50.756 42       40
```

More documentation can be found at:
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cols/

Comment: Is there a way to do this using each? Because if I have 100 columns, typing out each one would be annoying